# Find C# code source for event handler from debugger?

Tags: c#, debugging, events

I am debugging on a large code base and I’d like to know what functions are attached to some C# event
Using GetInvocationList() in the debugger I can successfully get the list of delegates attached to the event, but is there a way to find where in my source code the delegate is defined? Basically I am trying to identify the actual delegate that I obtain in debug mode using GetInvocationList(), is such a thing possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Delegate (base type for System.Eventhandler) has a Method property which is type System.Reflection.MethodInfo, but it is actually an instance of System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo if you add a breakpoint and check it out in the Locals window.

Looks like you can get the info you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use [Just Code](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) use [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to do some code analysis

Note: I do not work for Red Gate or Telerik